# How to compare 2 different payment schedules over 20 year period

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, finance

I have 2 options for a payment plan and need to calculate the total overall the best option.

Both plans are over a 20 years. The total payment amount is identical in both cases but the amounts at each stage very.

Im rusty on basic economics but if I remember correctly this is similar to a FV calculation

Plan A:
2000 month for 3 years = 72000
1500 month 3 years = 54000
1000 month for 11 years = 132000

Plan B
2500 month for 1 year = 30000
2000 month for 2 years = 48000
1500 month for for 40 months
1000 month for 10 years = 120000

I think that i need to do a FV calculation for each option and choose the smaller

Would appreciate an explanation and spreadsheet formula

Comment: This calculation is not possible without an interest rate also being given.

Comment: Assume 5% or any numbee

Comment: I would be interested to learn which actual firms make these two offers.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the numbers again plan B is simply worse (assuming a non-negative interest rate). In *any* specific month you look at, you have to pay *no less* under plan B than under plan A.